# I set the value of a variable but when I use get the parameter is null

Tags: java, get

Just want to ask what could be the problem with my java program.

I set the value of "id" variable in a particular class in my java program and
I printed the value of the variable to make sure it has been set.

I used a script to run a class in the same java program and then get the value of "id" but it returned null.

What could be the problem of my code?

Thanks!

So I made the ChargeParamData a singleton class which is then accessed by ChargeFacade to set/get data.

The script that I created will call the notifyAuthenticationStatus of the Chargefacade class. But when it is called pluginId is null.

This is the get/set class

```
public class ChargeParamData {

    private static final ChargeParamData instance = new ChargeParamData();

    /**
     * Returns the instance of the class
     * 
     * @return instance of the class
     */
    public static ChargeParamData getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     */
    private ChargeParamData() {
    }

    //for PluginId
    private static String pluginId;

    public static void setPluginId(String id) {
        pluginId = id;
        System.out.println("pluginId to set for Charge is " + pluginId);
    }

    public static String getPluginId() {
        System.out.println("pluginId to get for console test is " + pluginId);
        return pluginId;
    }
}
```

This is the code that uses the class:

```
public final class ChargeFacade {
    private static ChargeParamData chargeParam = ChargeParamData.getInstance();

    public static void chargePluginInit() {
        String pid = null;
        PluginDescriptor[] pdList = sample.listPlugin();
        pid = pdList[0].getId();
        createContext(pid);
    }

    private static void createContext(String pluginId) {
        chargeParam.setPluginId(pluginId);
        logger.info("Charge Service created for " + pluginId);
    }

    public static String notifyAuthenticationStatus(AuthenticationStatus authStat) throws DispatcherException {
        String pluginId = chargeParam.getPluginId(); // <-- this part is null
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            authStat.putInto(json);
            retVal = sample.callFunction(pluginId, "notifyAuthenticationStatus", json.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: i edited the code to show how the value is set and get. thank you

Comment: @user3388797 what is `chargeParam`?

Comment: it's a class where the parameters are kept. ChargeParam and ChargeFacade are both in the same folder.

Comment: yes `ChargeFacade`  is a class(from the above codes,I can see) but what is ChargeParam

Comment: Is your `chargePluginInit()` called from somewhere ?

Comment: @JqueryLearner Do you mean what does the ChargeParam do? i only created the class so that i can keep all the parameters i set in one class then get them when i need them. sorry, i am new to java and the terminologies.

Comment: where is chargeParam declared ?

Comment: it is inside the Chargefacade class, sorry i forgot to include it because the code is too long. i edited the code.

Comment: @user3388797 I think you are calling the getter and setter of ChargeParamData class

Comment: sorry i added more info. @JqueryLearner thanks for your help and i edited the question to have more info

Answer (score 0):

As the getter and setter methods are defined in `ChargeParamData`

```
    public class ChargeParamData {

//for PluginId
private static String pluginId;

public static void setPluginId(String id) {
    pluginId = id;
    System.out.println("pluginId to set for Charge is " + pluginId);
}

public static String getPluginId() {
    System.out.println("pluginId to get for console test is " + pluginId);
    return pluginId;
}
}

this is the code that uses the class

public final class ChargeFacade {
private static ChargeParamData chargeParam = ChargeParamData.getInstance();

public static void chargePluginInit() {
    String pid = null;
PluginDescriptor[] pdList = sample.listPlugin();
    pid = pdList[0].getId();
    createContext(pid);
}

private static void createContext(String pluginId) {

    ChargeParamData .setPluginId(pluginId);
    logger.info("Charge Service created for " + pluginId);
}


public static String notifyAuthenticationStatus(AuthenticationStatus authStat) throws DispatcherException {
    String pluginId = ChargeParamData .getPluginId(); // <-- this part is null
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        authStat.putInto(json);
        retVal = sample.callFunction(pluginId, "notifyAuthenticationStatus",
                json.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retVal;
}
}
```